# WordPress independent functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, bbpress

I have a fresh WordPress and bbPress installed on an internal server.

While I was setting up bbPress I wanted to test the functionalities like creating a forum, topic, etc. When doing these stuff in the back-end *(dashboard)* there didn't seem to be any problems but when I did it from the front-end I kept getting

`ERROR: Are you sure you wanted to do that?`

I searched for a solution and found [this](https://bbpress.org/forums/topic/error-are-you-sure-you-wanted-to-do-that-3/#post-142468).

> ```
> add_filter( 'bbp_verify_nonce_request_url', 'my_bbp_verify_nonce_request_url', 999, 1 );
> function my_bbp_verify_nonce_request_url( $requested_url )
> {
>   return 'http://localhost:8888' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
> }
> ```

I simply changed the hard-coded URL to what our internal server is set up to and it fixed the problem.

---

Now my question: is it possible for me to add this solution to a `functions.php` that is independent of the theme being used? I asked this because I have 2 concerns:

- The current theme might get updated and will overwrite the file

I'm aware that the solution to this is simply create a child theme but my second concern prevents me from doing this.

- The WordPress administrator might change themes and so both the `functions.php` file on the main theme and the child theme will stop working

---

How could I add the solution above so that I don't have to worry about the theme being updated and/or replaced with a new theme in the future? I don't want to keep adding this solution every time the administrator decides to change themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't put it in a theme, put it in a Plugin. If you're worried that the plugin will get de-activated make it a [Must Use Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins).

It's dead simple to create a plugin. Create a file `plugin-name.php` and place it in a directory `wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/`. That file should contain the following code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Name Of The Plugin
Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0
Author: Name Of The Plugin Author
Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
*/

add_filter( 'bbp_verify_nonce_request_url', 'my_bbp_verify_nonce_request_url', 999, 1 );
function my_bbp_verify_nonce_request_url( $requested_url )
{
  return 'http://localhost:8888' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

If you want it to be a must use plugin, put it in `wp-content/mu-plugins/` instead of `wp-content/plugins`.

Comment: While I do like this idea, I'm not familiar with WP theme/plugin development. Thanks though!

Comment: It's super simple to create a plugin. Added all the instructions you'll need to my answer above.

Comment: Oh cool, thanks! Will try this out after a couple hours, on my way for a meeting at the moment.